# Stored procedure still return same result with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure called `GetContactsByUserId @userId INT`.

I want to call this stored procedure with Entity Framework Core (7.0.0-rc1-final).

The stored procedure return these types in the result:

```
ContactId INT, ContactName NVARCHAR(200)
```

I have created in C# the object called - `Contact`:

```
[Key]
public int ContactId {get; set;}

public string ContactName {get;set;}
```

And this DbSet:

```
public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

I've tried call the stored procedure like this:

```
_dbContext.Set<Contact>().FromSql("dbo.GetContactsByUserId @userId = {0}", userid);
```

After first call I get for example 30 rows. I add new records and try again call this procedure with the same parameter and I get 30 rows not 31 rows.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you called _dbcontext.SaveChanges(); after you added new contacts? That is, are you sure they are in the database?

I mocked up a console example using a stored procedure to list contacts and it works as expected. It returns the correct number of contacts the first time as well as after I add additional contacts.

Here is my ListContacts code in case it helps:

```
    public static List<Contact> ListContacts()
    {
        var contacts = new List<Contact>();           

        using (var db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var contactsSQL = db.Set<Contact>().FromSql("dbo.GetContacts");

            foreach (var contactSQL in contactsSQL)
            {
                var contact = new Contact();
                contact.ID = contactSQL.ID;
                contact.Name = contactSQL.Name;
                contacts.Add(contact);
            }

            return contacts;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, what version of EF Core did you use on this sample?

Comment: The packages I'm using are all "7.0.0-rc1-final"